# dhcpclient linux - error messages during obtaining lease from router

Tags: linux, dhcp

as a linux debian  client of tplink deco router with fixed ip reservation on router i get this:

```
eth0: offered 192.168.68.111 from 192.168.68.1
Oct 26 20:22:42 home dhcpcd[654]: eth0: NAK: REQUEST for invalid Requested IP Address from 192.168.1.1
Oct 26 20:22:42 home dhcpcd[654]: eth0: message: REQUEST for invalid Requested IP Address
```

192.168.68.11 is OK this is configured on the router software
192.168.68.1 is the router IP...
but i don't know why there is a 192.168.1.1 in the logs... it's also used as a resolv.conf entry:
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.68.1
which is obviously bad there is no 192.168.1.1 in the network.

cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.68.111;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 7200;
  option routers 192.168.68.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.68.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1,192.168.68.1;
  renew 3 2022/10/26 21:02:02;
  rebind 3 2022/10/26 21:59:27;
  expire 3 2022/10/26 22:14:27;
}
```

any ideas?

i just want to get rid of the warnings ;)

Comment: And why you didn't removed that optional DNS 192.168.1.1 since it is in other subnet?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the server configuration file if 192.168.1.1 is configured as dns server.